# How do we call c# method under Saxon HE 9

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have very big XML and a xsl. I created a C# method to connect database and included that method like XSLT1.0 which we can connect to c# method. But here nothing is working.

Please tell me the way of connecting to c# functions in Saxon HE 9.

Comment: Have you read the official documentation https://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-fns-N.html and looked at the samples/resources https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/samples/cs/ExamplesHE.cs?

Comment: Thanks I got the answer after your document